# react-select, cannot change color of text in placeholder within text box

Tags: reactjs

Trying to set the color of the default select value to black but it doesn't work, i even put !important so it overrides any bootstrap colors that being overwritten by it. Any help is appreciated thank you.

```
const colourStyles = {
      control: styles => ({ ...styles, overflow: 'hidden', color: 'black !important',backgroundColor: this.state.selectedOption.value || '#32CD32', fontSize: 23,  paddingLeft: 'center', height:46}),
      singleValue: styles => ({ ...styles, color: 'black' }),
    }
<Select
 onChange={this.handleChange}
 options={optionsStatus}
 styles={colourStyles}
 placeholder= 'Status'
/>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 24):

You can update the placeholder styles using the same `colourStyles` object.

```
const colourStyles = {
    placeholder: (defaultStyles) => {
        return {
            ...defaultStyles,
            color: '#ffffff',
        }
    }
}
```

You can review the related documentation (https://react-select.com/styles#style-object) to check the keys available for styling.

Answer (score 9):

If someone is looking for changing text and style

```
<Select 
options={options} 
placeholder={<div className="select-placeholder-text">Select category</div>} 
/>
```

In the Stylesheet

```
.select-placeholder-text {
color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to override the default theme. According to [react-select](https://react-select.com/styles#overriding-the-theme) docs, the neutral50 response for placeholder's color. For example:

```
<Select
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    options={optionsStatus}
    styles={colourStyles}
    placeholder= 'Status'
    theme={theme => ({
        ...theme,
        colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            neutral50: '#1A1A1A',  // Placeholder color
        },
    })}
/>
```

View on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-codesandboxer-example-vth0i?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this too.  I kept trying to change `::placeholder` in the css, but it seems to be rendered as actual text, not a pseudo-class.  Here's what I found that worked.  First, pass the prop `classNamePrefix="react-select"` to the component, and then select it in the css with:

```
.react-select__placeholder {
  color: black;
}
```

(And of course, you can make the classNamePrefix whatever you want).

Answer (score 1):

For version `5.7.3`, I changed it this way:

```js
theme={(theme) => ({
            ...theme,
            colors: {
              neutral50: "#fff",
            },
          })}
```